# Powershell to save sql return dataset into csv file

Tags: sql, powershell, csv

I have the following script to run a script and to return the dataset when I would like the result saved into the folder under csv formet:

```
$connectionString = "Data Source=$sqlserver; User ID = $username; Password = $pws;Initial Catalog=$database;" 

$connection = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection
$connection.ConnectionString = $connectionString

$connection.Open()

$query = “SELECT TOP 5 * FROM Test”

$command = $connection.CreateCommand()
$command.CommandText = $query

$result = $command.ExecuteReader()

$result |export-csv c:\temp\Test.csv -notypeinformation

$connection.Close()
```

It's generate the csv file, however the contains inside the csv file is the fields count of each row of the dataset instead of the dataset itself. Does anyone know what is going wrong with my script?

Answer (score 0):

Try to change your $result variable from $command.ExecuteReader() to an invoke-sqlcmd

```
$result = invoke-sqlcmd -query $query -serverinstance $sqlserver -database $database
```